# Function declaration is not global if from a different file, if not assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm creating a program in Meteor JS. All the JS files are loaded at once, in a certain order.

A lot of variables need to be global, in order to work, but at the same time, I want my JS to be modular.

For FILE 3 to use the functions in FILE 1 and FILE 2, the functions have to be declared as variable assignments like in FILE 2 or else, they are not accessible outside of the file. I don't believe this is an issue of hoisting, because main.js is loaded last, those are the functions that use the functions in FILE 1 and 2. Either way, I theoretically should be able to see the function in the console if it is on a global level.

FILE 1

`function foo() { } // This is not global outside of the file. Why?`

FILE 2

`bar = function() { } // This is considered global.`

Functions in FILE 1 can access the function just fine, but if placed outside the file, the function or console cannot access them.

Is this a Meteor JS thing? A JavaScript thing? Someone help me understand and learn. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is being wrapped in a function, so variables and function literals create *local* variables.

However, if you assign to a name that has not been declared, that will create a global variable.

You should add `'use strict';` to turn that into an error instead.